# How do I ignore the notification id when creating a Chrome notification?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In the documentation of [`chrome.notifications.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#method-create), `notificationId` is marked as optional.

But when I try to invoke this function ignoring `notificationId`, I get an uncaught error:

> Uncaught Error: Invocation of form notifications.create(object, function) doesn't match definition notifications.create(string notificationId, object options, function callback)

**EDIT**: I've added version information of my browser.
[image]

Comment: What Chrome version?

Comment: @RetoAebersold I guess it's Chrome 41. I've added a snippet of `chrome://version` in my question description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `notificationId` parameter is required before Chrome 42. See the [chrome.notifications documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#method-create).